# site moved to a new server and now pdfs wont download

Tags: pdf, joomla

I had a joomla 1.5 site for a couple of years on a linux cpanel - everything was running fine. Last week we moved it to a new linux server and now we have a strange problem.  The general navigation etc works fine but linking to pdfs seems to have gone "Random". For example there are 4 pdf links on this page http://www.coinstreet.org/spacehire/conferencemeetings.html - they all have different links. However, for 3 of them the same pdf is downloaded (despite the different links) and one doesn't work at all - get a 406 error.

The new install was taken by doing a straight backup of the cpanel and then a re-install. All other functionality seems to be fine.

I am at a bit of a loss - so any suggestions would be gratefully received!

PS Just noticed that I see a lot of lines like this in the error logs

`[Sat Mar 31 14:50:10 2012] [error] [client 65.92.86.225] File does not exist: /data03/c9566644/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.coinstreet.org/images/stories/coinstreet/JDPS%20Childcare%20Assistant.pdf`
don't know if that's relevant?

UPDATE
I created a test link to fred.pdf that DIDN'T exist on the server. WHen the link is clicked rather than giving an error as expected a pdf was downloaded. TUrns out that several pdfs are missing it seems and that this same file is downloaded. When I put a fred.pdf on the server then the test link worked as expected. So, where is this "Wrong" pdf coming from...

ANother update
I have now discovered that the same problem was happening on the old server... too oh boy!
Also, the mystery pdf that downloads is actually part of one of the articles on the site, turned into a pdf on the fly. If I unpublish that article then I get just a blank pdf appear. Time to look closely at the .htaccess file me thinks... anyone else got any thoughts?

Comment: I went through some other pages in your site (I like the design). In general most pdf links don't work, however in the jobs sections there are two pages where they do work as expected. Did you refresh cache ? double checked your files/paths ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes cleared the cache numerous times. Thing is all was fine on the old server. Now like you say, it seems most don't work at all but some do (and weirdly download the same files as other links). I have also been onto the host who say that there is nothing wrong with the server and that it might be something to do with the .htaccess file. So I replaced ours with a brand new un altered one from the joomla files and it made no difference.

Comment: THis is not a programming question.  It should be closed and moved to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: actually, he more I look at it the more I think it is some sort of programming error. The latest I have found is that, unknown to me, some similar behaviour was occuring on the old server too!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the filename typed in wrongly!

The link you have on your site:

```
http://www.coinstreet.org/images/stories/coinstreet/Meeting%20Space%20User%20Special%20Requirements%20Policy3.pdf
```

The link I used to see the `PDF` successfully:

```
http://www.coinstreet.org/images/stories/coinstreet/Meeting%20Space%20User%20Special%20Requirements%20Policy(3).pdf
```

Notice the `(` `)` around the `3`

Comment: I just found that the if i did ...Policy3.pdf the right file downloaded and that if I did Policy(3).pdf instread of saying no file it downloads the wrong one!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing the results of two different effects here:

a) Some form of incorrect encoding when the files were uploaded - clearly the spaces and extended characters in the file name are being url encoded prior to saving. I've seen ftp programs do this and I've also seen Joomla do this periodically. I don't know if cPanel backups don't sometimes do this too. Best advice I can give is to always rename files to remove spaces(swapping for hyphens) as well as stripping brackets, ampersands and exclamation marks (bangs). Train users to do likewise to avoid these issues - and check error logs periodically to pick up on anything you miss or that changes.

b) Now with your requests for the files not matching the actual filename you would expect to see 404 errors - but sometimes you get a file, not always the right one though. My guess here is that you have the apache module that attempts to match files based on misspellings - sorry can't recall the exact name off hand. A quick search shows mod_speling (mis-spelling of spelling is deliberate) is the most likely contender.

Comment: that's a really helpful answer Dean - I will go and investigate. What I have found is that when the file is missing its not pulling in another pdf, but its pulling in one of the articles (now unpublished) and converting that to a pdf (hence why I thought it was a pdf). Any thoughts on that one? Thanks again!

Comment: Here's a bit more. I have got the orriginal word doc, re-converted to a pdf, and uploaded with no sillies in the file name. Some borwsers download it all, IE and FF freeze, chrome shows its downloading and the helpfully says "Failed to download pdf"